# Show that $|F_{X,Y}(x,y)|^2\leq F_X(x)F_Y(y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Consider the random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined in the same space $\Omega$.
>   Show that  $$|F_{X,Y}(x,y)|^2\leq F_X(x)F_Y(y)$$

This question comes from an old test, I know that
$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X\leq x\cap Y\leq y)$$
$$F_X(x)=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y)$$
$$F_Y(y)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y)$$
 but I do not the slightest idea how to prove it.

Comment: Writing \lim with a backslash in MathJax or LaTeX (1) makes $\lim$ appear un-italicized; (2) results in proper spacing in expressions like $a\lim b$; (3) in a displayed, rather than inline, setting, it affects position of the subscript so that you see $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}$ with the subscript direction below $\lim$.  I edited accordingly. (I've up-voted the question and Conrado Costa's answer.) ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X\leq x\cap Y\leq y) \leq P(X\leq x)$$

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X\leq x\cap Y\leq y) \leq P(Y\leq y)$$

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)^2\leq P(X\leq x) P(Y\leq y)$$